# Error in your SQL syntax with multiselect

Tags: mysql, sql, pymysql

Good day!

I have some problem with mysql syntax. I need to select only those name that have maximum `SID` more than, input value '​​count'
I tried to do it with pymysql like:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `files` WHERE


SELECT `sid` FROM `origin_files` WHERE `name` LIKE %s
ORDER BY `sid` DESC LIMIT 1 >= %s",(name, count);
```

Mysql said that there error in syntax.

desc files:

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name  | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| sid   | int(4)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| path  | varchar(200) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

desc origin_files:

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name  | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| sid   | int(4)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| path  | varchar(200) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I would be grateful if you help solve this problem.

Comment: Please post the result of these querys: `show create table files;` and `show create table origin_files;`

Comment: What is the relation of files and origin_file? It is really hard to tell what you need the outcome to be, please try to explain with another words.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT field
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE field IN
    (SELECT field
     FROM TABLE_NAME
     WHERE field LIKE '%s'
     ORDER BY field DESC);
```

Comment: You shouldn't have edited user3145373's incorrect answer. Rather, you should have just down-voted it and added this correct solution. As it is, you made them look better, and you'll get no credit (and risk getting down-voted yourself for 'copying' them! :-/)

Comment: full answer is not wrong just need some modification so i edited answer. Thank you...

Comment: `LIMIT 1 >= '%s', (name, count)`?